# Which champions have pets?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which champions have pets? I know Annie has one (Tibbers) and Heimerdinger has something of a pet (not sure what it is called). Are there any others?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer right now so here is a link to the Pet wiki page. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Pet I will be back to do a more finished answer later.

Comment: @AdamP That's fine, take your time. I'm in no big hurry :).

Comment: I could have sworn i've seen this question before... hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really all depends on your definition of 'pet'.

According to the [LoL wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Pets):

- A *pet* is a minion only responsive to a Champion. Some pets have their own health, some are controllable, some are static and some help cast abilities.

  - Annie's [Summon Tibbers](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Annie#Summon_Tibbers)
  - Mordekaiser's [Children of the Grave](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mordekaiser#Children_of_the_Grave)
  - Yorick's [Omen of Death](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yorick#Omen_of_Death)
  - Elise's [Spider Swarm](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elise#Spider_Swarm)
  - Heimerdinger's [H-28G Evolution Turret](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heimerdinger#H-28G_Evolution_Turret)
  - Malzahar's  [Summon Voidling](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Malzahar#Summon_Voidling)
  - Shaco's [Jack In The Box](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco#Jack_In_The_Box)
  - Yorick's [Omen of War](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yorick#Omen_of_War), [Omen of Pestilence](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Omen_of_Pestilence) and [Omen of Famine](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Omen_of_Famine)
  - Zyra's [Rampant Growth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zyra#Rampant_Growth)
- A *decoy* is a pet that's considered as a Champion in almost all respects (such as tower priority, valid targets, etc), except that their damage is still credited to their owner (and so will attract tower aggro as with any champion damage).

  - LeBlanc's [Mirror Image](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/LeBlanc#Mirror_Image)
  - Shaco's [Hallucinate](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco#Hallucinate)
  - Wukong's [Decoy](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wukong#Decoy)
- A few pets act as *traps* or wards:

  - Elise's [Volatile Spiderling](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elise#Volatile_Spiderling)
  - Maokai's [Sapling Toss](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Maokai#Sapling_Toss)
- The following look like pets but don't quite behave like that:

  - Lulu's [Pix](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu#Pix.2C_Faerie_Companion)
  - Quinn's [Valor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Valor)
  - Swain's [Beatrice](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Swain#Carrion_Renewal)
  - Orianna's [ball](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Orianna#Command:_Attack)
  - Syndra's [Dark Sphere](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Syndra#Dark_Sphere)
  - Viktor's [Chaos Storm](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Viktor#Chaos_Storm)
  - Zed's [Living Shadow](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Living_Shadow) and [Death Mark](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Death_Mark)
  - Janna's [Zephyr](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna#Zephyr)
- A number of pets are just for *cosmetic* effect as part of their ability sets; see a list [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Pets#Companions).

Comment: Complete and perfect answer !!

Comment: We try to avoid duplicating large amounts of content from outside sources.  Usually best practice is to summarize in your own words, perhaps quote a relevant section, and then leave a link to the full article elsewhere.  Would you mind paring down the amount of copied information?